# Why has Kerberos authentication stopped working after migration from Apache 2.2 to 2.4

Tags: apache, kerberos

I have a pair of Solaris intranet servers, (live and Dev)
We have upgraded Apache from 2.2 to 2.4.37 on Dev, but Kerberos authentication no longer works, unless I turn `KrbLocalUserMapping Off`  which breaks things later on (LDAP authentication to AD)
MIT Kerberos libraries are freshly compiled, as is mod_auth_kerb.

The (live) config looks like:

```
AuthType Kerberos
Krb5Keytab /usr/local/apache2/myname.keytab
KrbMethodNegotiate on
KrbMethodK5Passwd on
KrbServiceName HTTP

KrbLocalUserMapping On

#mod_authnz_ldap configuration
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ex.am.ple.com/dc=ex,dc=am,dc=ple,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?
(objectClass=*)" NONE

AuthLDAPBindDN "srv-myname@ex.am.ple.com"
AuthLDAPBindPassword myPassword
AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN On

# Prevent needless search on uniquemember attr
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
```

There is nothing in the Apache error logs (debug mode) to indicate what is wrong, other than "no authenticated user yet".
Turning `KrbLocalUserMapping` to `On` instantly makes the authentication work, but I then need to do an LDAP group lookup, which fails as the user-name no longer matches.

Comment: I've been snooping the network interface, and can see that with `KrbLocalUserMapping Off` there is LDAP traffic, but none with `KrbLocalUserMapping On`.